# How can I view the database created by Entity Framework in UWP using a viewer?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, win-universal-app

I created an app that creates a database by EntityFramework. I created a class that inherits `DbContext` and made configurations. I have this abstract method implemented also.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=People.db");
}
```

Like what I have said in the title, how can I view People.db? I have checked the directory and it is not there so it looks like it's something built in. For convenience, how can I modify its contents on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the database file `People.db` will be created in the [local folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder) of your current app. If your app is running on the PC device you may find it on `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Packages\{your app package family name}\LocalState`. Local folder directory can be read/right, which is suit for your to modify and save contents. More details about file access permissions on UWP please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) .

You may also setup the [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt) to have a GUI to see the database data.

More details please reference [Getting Started with EF Core on Universal Windows Platform (UWP) with a New Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started). This sample contains how to create a database and insert data at run-time.